# Mixed Date format during import from Access into Excel

Tags: vba, ms-access, import, date-format

I am having some trouble importing data from Access, some date formats are inversed for exemple, in the database 02 octobre turns into 10 february in my import, while 29 september stays the same.

On the Access database, the dates are in date format. it seems that during the import, the only dates that are not inversed are imported as strings which is not what i want so 29/09/2017 is imported as a string. And the dates date are imported in date format have the month and date inversed, so 02/10/2017 is imported as 10/02/2017 and is recognized in excel as 10 february.

Here is the part of my code where i retrieve the data from access

```
Dim str_req As String

str_req = "SELECT  " & param_champs & " FROM Histo a, Referential b WHERE   a.productID = b.ID  AND  a.Isin IN " & sicoList


Dim recordset As New ADODB.recordset

recordset.Open str_req, objConn, adOpenDynamic
Worksheets("test").Range(Cells(2, colref), Cells(1500, colref + 2 + WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("test.champs")))) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(recordset.GetRows)
```

If anyone has an idea of what might cause this problem and how to solve this, it would really help me as i'm not an expert in Access.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have where you set your `param_champs`, but within that string, you could add this SQL (providing the proceeding 0 is always there in your source on both the month and the day 01/01)

```
CDATE(MID(date_column , 4, 3) & LEFT(date_column,3) & RIGHT(date_column, 4))
```

If you have table write access, and it won't break anything, it would be better to fix this in the table itself. You could do this with an update statement.

```
UPDATE temptemp
SET date_column = MID(date_column , 4, 3) & LEFT(date_column,3) & 
RIGHT(date_column, 4);
```

After, in the design view of the table, change the date field to date/time datatype.